# Android: RecyclerView stackfromEnd is ignored

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to setup a RecyclerView with LinearLayoutManager and stackfromEnd.

I've tried setting it completely programmatically and in xml, but none of both did work.

```xml
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/comments_view"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
          app:stackFromEnd="true"
          app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
          app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/commen_send_bar"
          app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier"/>
```

```
comments_view = v.findViewById(R.id.comments_view)
val linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity!!)
linearLayoutManager.stackFromEnd = true
comments_view.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
```

Comment: Did you try calling `recyclerview.invalidate()` after setting the layout manager?

Comment: @ZohaibAmir I did now and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you try removing the XML attributes  `app:layoutManager` and `          app:stackFromEnd="true"` and just set it dynamically to see if it works? lastly, call `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()`

Comment: I removed both and called notifyDataSetChanges(), but it still does not work.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? it is possible that stackFromEnd does diffrent job than what you intend to do

Comment: I am trying to achieve that the list starts at the bottom. I was using ListView with stackFromBottom before and it did it exactly as I wanted. Now I switched to RecyclerView and it stopped working.

Comment: did you set layout direction anywhere in the parent?

Comment: The parent is a Constraint Layout without any specified orientation

Comment: @BlindJerobine were you able to resolve this issue? I am having the same exact issue

Comment: @displayname Sadly, no :(

Comment: @BlindJerobine, two years since your last comment. were you able to resolve this issue meanwhile?